# What is the current method for server/client network connections

Tags: java, sockets

I haven't used Java for along time. Googling seems to bring up a lot of different methods.

What is the current, modern, accepted method for TCP socket connections these days? I don't want to implement something that is going to become deprecated soon.

If it matters, I will be sending JSON bidirectionally between client and server and would like non-blocking sending and receiving and blocking initial connections.

From what I can see, ServerSocketChannel looks pretty recent (I hadn't heard about it until now)...is that what I should be using?

Comment: The answer by Peter Lawrey below is absolutely valid; but I am wondering what type of application you are building. Would it be relevant to think in terms of e.g. Apache Camel or an application server like Tomcat to deal with your I/O requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the current, modern, accepted method for TCP socket connections these days?

You can use Netty or Mina, but I would use just Plain IO and perhaps blocking NIO as I believe these are the simplest.  All of these have been around about ten years or more.

> I don't want to implement something that is going to become deprecated soon.

I can't think of the last time anything was truly deprecated in Java.

> ServerSocketChannel looks pretty recent

It was added in Java 1.4 in 2002. ;)

Despite what most sites will suggest, I believe blocking NIO is simpler to work with (and it can be faster for a small number of connections)

If all you want to do is send and receive JSON text, I would use Plain IO.  I would use an ExecutorService to manage the threads you need to support this.  These were added in 2004, but are actually much older.

Comment: When you say "Plain IO", what do you mean? I assume you are referring to the `java.io` package, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yes, the original IO is simpler when sending and parsing text. IMHO.

Comment: The Java NIO looks far more interesting, so I am going to give that a go as a learning exercise. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Ben NIO is more interesting. ;)

Comment: Got any good resources on NIO which is done properly for highly scalable servers? Seems there are a fair few ways of handling it and not many deal with expensive read/write methods as that would slow everything down.

Comment: I believe best practice is being able to change your framework fairly easily.  This is because you can easily find that want to change how your solution works.  Note: If you use Plain IO (the simplest) you can still scale to 1000 active connections easily.  If you use blocking NIO you can scale to 10,000 active connections, if you use non-blocking IO you can scale more in theory, but in practice there is a very limited need for such solutions as your server needs to do something useful.

Comment: The more connections you have, the less of the server each user has. e.g. if you have 10 cores and each request takes 10 milli-seconds, you might sustain only 1000 requests per second.

Comment: If you providing a high value service you might want to spend $1-10 per user per year on hardware and support.  This means a $2000 server can handle about 200-2000 actual (rather than concurrent users)  There are services where you want to spend far less than $1 per user, but they are also services which are well covered by existing companies.

Comment: I was more interested in the ability to scale to what I want. So you say that non-blocking NIO can scale, which would mean that I could load balance without having to worry about the number of connections (up to a point) that a particular server is actually handling, so it could manage 20,000 active connections doing nothing or very little.

Comment: This assumes your program does next to nothing. If your program does something significant, I would assume what your program does will determine your scalability limits in which case a more complex IO solution may not help (in fact it may make understanding and tuning your program harder)

Comment: I can always vertically scale my hardware as newer faster hardware comes out in the future. It means I can use the same code and just fiddle with the limit I set for the number of the connections...does that make sense?

Comment: This isn't always enough, but it's one option you should consider.  You can scale an application by making it more efficient, one a faster machine, or across more machines.  At the end, the solution should help you meet the application's requirements.